# Flex: Custom composite component in ActionScript -- problems with percentWidth/percentHeight

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

I've done tons of research and read the [Adobe Live Docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=size_position_2.html) till my eyes bled trying to figure this out.

I am building a composite custom component in ActionScript, and would like the sub controls to be laid out horizontally. This works fine by adding them to an `HGroup` and adding HGroup to the component, the problem comes with percentage based sizing.

I need `_horizontalGroup:HGroup` to size it self based on the size of its container.

stepping through the code shows that the parent properties of each UIComponent are...

- _horizontalGroup.parent = ReportGridSelector
- ReportGridSelector.parent = grpControls

If grpControls has an explicit size, shouldn't ReportGridSelector have its size as well?

The custom component is implemented like this...
NOTE: ReportControl extends UIComponent and contains no sizing logic

```
public class ReportGridSelector extends ReportControl{

  /*other display objects*/
  private var _horizontalGroup:HGroup;

    public function ReportGridSelector(){
        super();
        percentHeight = 100;
        percentWidth = 100;
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void{

        super.createChildren();

        if(!_horizontalGroup){
            _horizontalGroup = new HGroup();

            //I WANT SIZE BY PERCENTAGE, BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK
            _horizontalGroup.percentWidth = 100;
            _horizontalGroup.percentHeight = 100;

            //EXPLICITLY SETTING THEM WORKS, BUT IS STATIC :-(
            //_horizontalGroup.width = 200;
            //_horizontalGroup.height = 200;
            addChild(_horizontalGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

Consuming MXML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<s:VGroup id="grpControls" width="200" height="200">
     <ReportControls:ReportGridSelector width="100%" height="100%"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

If I explicitly define `_horizontalGroup`'s `width` and `height` properties, everything displays fine. If I try `_horizontalGroup.percentWidth` or `percentHeight`, all the controls get scrunched together.

Any thoughts as to what is going on?

Comment: Also here are some related posts that I've found. [Flex:CreateNewComponent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489024/flex-how-to-create-an-entirely-new-component)
[Flex Custom Component PercentWidth/Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473085/flex-custom-component-percentage-width-height)
[How to get Flex components to fill available space using ActionScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090845/how-to-get-flex-components-to-fill-available-space-using-actionscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform layout when the display list is invalidated from updateDisplayList.

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

    _horizontalGroup.width = unscaledWidth;
    _horizontalGroup.height = unscaledHeight;
}
```

Understand the Flex component lifecycle:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html

**createChildren**

> Creates any child components of the component. For example, the
>   ComboBox control contains a TextInput control and a Button control as
>   child components.
>
> For more information, see Implementing the createChildren() method.

**updateDisplayList**

> Sizes and positions the children of the component on the screen based
>   on all previous property and style settings, and draws any skins or
>   graphic elements used by the component. The parent container for the
>   component determines the size of the component itself.

Comment: Thanks Jason that worked like a charm! I am slowly making the transition away from MXML implemented components and will revisit the life cycle.